# Error vue project with scss | problem windows or modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, vue.js, sass

```
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:29764:51)
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles\index.scss 2:11  root stylesheet
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\components\utils\Icon\index.vue 2:11  root stylesheet
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\components\Login\styles.scss 2:11  root stylesheet
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\components\CustomModal\index.vue 2:11  root stylesheet
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\components\Plan\UserInterface\styles.scss 2:11  root stylesheet
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\components\Plan\NotificationsButton\styles.scss 2:11  root stylesheet
[sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │           @use "C:\Users\eva\Documents\project2\station-plan\src/styles/variables.scss" as *;
  │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\components\NotificationsSidebar\styles.scss 2:11  root stylesheet
```

- npm install legacy peer deeps
- npm install
- npm run dev

my project is run in localhost8080
but I have this error

work in windows system.